# Error on Html.ActionLink

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an action link that when a user clicks on it, it redirects to an mvc view, the actionlink is below,

```
<%=Html.ActionLink("Select", "Review?usrItId=" + drResponse["ItineraryId"].ToString() +     "&Type=" + drResponse["FareType"].ToString(), "", new { @class = "fCheck" })%>
```

but when the user clicks on it i get the below error,
system.Web.HttpException: A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (?)

the HTML is presented like this:

```
<a class="fCheck" href="/controller/Review%3fusrItId%3dsi1000%26Type%3dNoFrills?Length=0">Select</a>
```

thanks in advance for the help. I am using MVC 3, .NET 3.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query parameters (`userItId` and `Type` here) need to be specified in a different way. It is what the `routeValues` argument of `ActionLink` is for:

```
<%=Html.ActionLink("Select", "Review", new { usrItId = drResponse["ItineraryId"].ToString(), Type = drResponse["FareType"].ToString() }, new { @class = "fCheck" })%>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your action link to this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Select", "Review", 
    new { usrItId = drResponse["ItineraryId"].ToString(), Type = drResponse["FareType"].ToString()}, 
    new {@class = "fCheck"})
```